# Change ID of webform hidden element

Tags: forms, 6, webforms

How can I change the ID of a hidden element (created with the Drupal 6 webform module) using hook_form_alter()?

The ID that it outputs is something like '#edit-submitted-component-name'. I need the ID to be something very custom and I need to avoid changing it with Javascript. The form API does not support the #atrributes token on hidden elements, so I can't set the ID via hook_form_alter();

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to deal with. I need to generate form IDs programmatically so I implemented below code.

```
function voci_comment_form($form, &$form_state, $cid) {
     $form['#attributes']['id'] = 'voci-comment-form-' . $cid;
     $form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'voci-comment-form';
     $form['body'] = array(
      '#title' => 'Post a comment',
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#resizable' => FALSE,
      '#rows' => 1,
     );
     $form['comment'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Comment',
     );

      return $form;
   }
```

It's true that you can set $element['#attributes']['id'] and that will apply to the form field.

I hope this helps... :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to set the ID attribute to a hidden element without affecting the form or any other element (<input type="hidden" id="custom-id" />). I checked the Drupal Form Api and $element['#attributes']['id'] is not supported for hidden elements.